# using git to version-control any file edited with my text editor

Tags: git, version-control, joe

Is there any way to integrate text editor (`joe` in my case) with `git` in such a way, that every change to any file is automatically committed in git (probably with a time stamp), so that I can always go back (revert changes) or diff changes of any files which I have edited?

I don't even know how that would work. Possibly with some wrapper script ?

Comment: Problem with a wrapper script is that it won't catch files you open from within the editor. (Emacs has hooks for intercepting that, but I'm unfamiliar with joe.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `vi` or `vim`, the following command added to the `.vimrc` file seems to work for me:

`` :autocmd BufWritePost * !git commit -a -m `date`" ``

Answer (score 0):

Very easy and automatic editor versioning can be done with vv, see:

http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/vv.html

It works with any editor and doers not need any other tools besides vv.